# Browser MIME type for playing H.264 video file

Tags: html5-video, h.264

I have a file produced from an encoding process that is in H.264 Annex B format, not wrapped in any container like MP4.  I'm trying to figure out how to make this file playable in browser using `<video>` element.  No matter what MIME type I try, it fails.

I know the file is good and browser has necessary facilities to decode it, because a) same exact content was previously streamed for WebRTC session that browser was able to decode and play, and b) the saved file is trivially playable with `ffplay myfile.h264`.

The HTML attempted for playing that file used the following `<source>` elements (ignore non-HTML formating pieces as those are cut from source-code directly):

```
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/avc'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/H264-SVC'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/H264'} />
<!-- Ones below are more of a desperation attempts :)  -->
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.66.13, mp4a.40.2"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42e01e, mp4a.40.2"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42e01e, mp4a.40.2"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.5"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001e, mp4a.40.5"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001f, mp4a.40.5"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.5"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d001e, mp4a.40.5'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d001f, mp4a.40.5"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.640029, mp4a.40.5'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d002a"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d001e, mp4a.40.2"'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'application/x-mpegurl'} />
<source src={this.props.src} type={'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'} />
```

None work.

Since browser can play it via WebRTC channel, and since it's trivially playable using `ffplay` (that is, format is self-describing and contains all necessary info for playback), I'd expect `<video>` to be able to play it.

Also small note, Android references AVC (aka h264) codec as `video/avc`, so that's where I pulled that one from, but that still fails.

What's the proper MIME type for playing straight up H.264 AVC content?

Comment: You need an MP4 container for AVC video data. That's the agreed standard between major browser brands. Maybe try `mux.js` to pack each AVC frame into fragmented MP4 (since that format allows MP4 to be streamed in frame-by-frame packets)

Comment: @VC.One, do you have a reference for the requirement of MP4 container? Because browsers are able to play naked AVC in WebRTC context and do not require MP4 wrapper there, and I find it odd that they would require MP4 for `<video>` element, or wonder why would they would require AVC to be containerized when it's intended to be playable on its own.

Comment: Yes it's odd but it's how things are setup in browsers... GIF plays multiple frames but `<canvas>` will only ever draw the first frame, even though `<image>` shows changing pixel data... MP3 will play without a container but AAC (which is MP3 v2) always needs an MP4/M4a container... H264 inside MP4 is ok but raw H264 alone is not allowed by the exact same decoder that will read same H264 in an MP4 anyways... MP3 will play but MP4 with MP3 audio track is silent (or at least in HLS streaming).

Comment: PS: See this [W3 guide for HTML5 video](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#best-practices-for-implementors-of-media-elements) as followed by major browser brands. FFplay can play H264 because it is using its own custom H264 decoder. So once again... To play H264 in browser it must in an MP4 container. JS tools like `Mux.js` or `Broadway` will take your input H264 and re-contain it for playback in the browser

Comment: PS: The correct section of [W3 guide for HTML5 video](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#the-source-element). It's called "The Source Element" and further on it shows the accepted MIME and expected containers for those codecs.

Comment: @VC.One, I looked at the section you referenced, but it seems to lack definition of what's supported and what's not.  The few examples it gives are, as the document states, "list shows some examples of" and is not an exhaustive list. I do, however, agree that it seems browsers are choosing not to implement naked AVC playback there, and simply as matter of choice. My guess would be that because it's video-only, usefulness of such implementation is very marginal, and thus not supported (but in WebRTC it is useful because video and audio channels there are usually decoupled intentionally).

Comment: @VC.One, ... so thank you for weighing in on this one as it gives at least partial clarification.  P.S. re ffmpeg/ffplay, I don't think it's really a matter of whether it is custom decoder or not (in fact, it can use nvenc which is not custom at all), but more so that that tool aims to be as functionally broad as possible, whereas browsers are more of common-ground approach.  So I'm off to my Plan B of having to containerize my video data.